# How to output logs at a different level then intended by spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-filter

I can log every incoming request by setting

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG
```

The requests will then be logged at level `DEBUG`. But I want them to be logged at level `INFO` instead. I don't think there is a flag for it but the loglevel is hardcoded by spring. But is there maybe some kind of filter that can intercept these logs and change their log level?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter that catches the request and logs it at the appropriate log level. Also, it would be wise to set it to `HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` so that it is executed before any other filters in the filter chain and logs the requests before some other filter modifies it.

```java
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CustomRequestLoggingFilter extends CommonsRequestLoggingFilter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomRequestLoggingFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // you have access to the HttpServletRequest obj so log whatever you want
        logger.info("Request:" + request.getMethod() + " " + request.getRequestURI());
        super.doFilterInternal(request, response, filterChain);

    }

}
```

Register it as a spring bean in your configuration class.

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CustomRequestLoggingFilter> loggingFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<CustomRequestLoggingFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new CustomRequestLoggingFilter());
        registrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return registrationBean;
    }

}
```